# Unable to pass dynamic form inputs to the controller function

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want a form to be created dynamically with three inputs each time a new data item is found. Whenever the end user clicks on a particular checkbox the selected field name, other input values corresponding to the form group have to be submitted to the controller function. I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satya76/wL6ykxv6/30/) for the layout.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="citycontroller as ctrl">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        Available Cities

     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <h4>
     {{data}}
     </h4>
         <div ng-repeat="x in data" class="[ form-group form-inline ]">
             <input class="form-control input-md" type="checkbox" id="{{x.name}}" ng-model="name" autocomplete="off" />
             <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                 <label for="{{x.name}}" class="[ btn btn-success ]">
                     <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                     <span> </span>
                 </label>                                                                    <label for="{{x.name}}" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                      {{x.name}}
                 </label>
             </div>
             <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" placeholder="periodicity" id="x.periodicity" autocomplete="off" />
         </div>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right" ng-click="ctrl.addInfo()">Add</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Controller method is as follows:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('cityinfo',[]);
mainApp.controller('citycontroller', function($scope,$http,$window,$interval) {

var cities=[{"name":"hyd","periodicity":"5"},{"name":"chn","periodicity":"5"},{"name":"blr","periodicity":"5"}];

$scope.data = cities;

this.addInfo=function() {
        console.log('update city information...');
        //get list of city names that are selected by the user in the form here and print their values
    }  
 });
```

Not getting idea about how to retrieve form values in the controller method addInfo(). Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to track which checkboxes are checked using ng-model.

One approach could be as follows.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="city.checked" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.cities = [{
    name: 'foo',
    periodicity: 5,
    checked: false
}, {
    name: 'bar'
    periodicity: 6,
    checked: false
}]

$scope.addInfo = function() {
    // Using lodash
    _($scope.cities).filter({checked: true}).each(function(city) {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your code at all. Just by changing the ng-model of your input you can achieve it:

HTML

```
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <h4>
     {{data}}
     </h4>
         <div ng-repeat="x in data" class="[ form-group form-inline ]">
             <input class="form-control input-md" type="checkbox" id="{{x.name}}" ng-model="x.value" autocomplete="off" />
             <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                 <label for="{{x.name}}" class="[ btn btn-success ]">
                     <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                     <span> </span>
                 </label>   
                 <label for="{{x.name}}" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                      {{x.name}}
                 </label>
             </div>
             <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" placeholder="periodicity" id="x.periodicity" autocomplete="off" />
         </div>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right" ng-click="ctrl.addInfo()">Add</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
            mainApp.controller('citycontroller', function($scope) {

var cities=[{"name":"hyd","periodicity":"5"},{"name":"chn","periodicity":"5"},{"name":"blr","periodicity":"5"}];

$scope.data = cities;

this.addInfo=function() {
        console.log($scope.data);
        //get list of city names that are selected by the user in the form here and print their values
    }  
 });
```

In your browser console check for value. It will be true if checkbox is selected.